# How to type a numpy array or scalar in cython?

Tags: cython

In normal python, both of these work just fine:

```
def from_db(db):
    return 10**(db/20)

from_db(45)
from_db(np.array([45, 46, 47]))
```

However in cython, I can't figure out how to type `db` so that I can still pass an array or a scalar.

```
def from_db(float db):
    return 10**(db/20)

# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
from_db(np.array([45, 46, 47]))

def from_db(cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t] db):
    return 10**(db/20)

# TypeError: Argument 'db' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got int)
from_db(45)

def from_db(float[:] db):
    return 10**(np.asarray(db)/20)

# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int' 
from_db(45)
```

Is there a way to achieve the old behavior with cython? Overloading seems like it would do it, but [that doesn't seem to be a thing in cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610108/is-overloading-broken-in-cppclass-cython-c-definitions), unfortunately